# Problema ao exibir imagem com UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, imagem, uiimage

Ao exibir imagem incluída no projeto no formato `.png` utilizando `UIImageView` para somente exibir a tela do simulador fica em branco.

Código utilizado:

```
UIImage* imagemLocal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
_imagemViewLocal = [UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:imagemLocal];
```

Ou:

```
UIImage* imagemLocal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
_imagemViewLocal = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

[_imagemViewLocal setImage: imagemLocal];
```

O resultado é o mesmo `ImageViewLocal` fica em branco.

OBS: Adicionei uma `UIImageView` pelo `Sotryboard` e liguei-a com `_imageViewLocal`.

---

Acabei realizando o seguinte teste:
- Removi o `UIImageView` criado no `Storyboard` e fiz tudo diretamente no código. E exibiu a imagem com o seguinte código:

```
UIImageView* imageViewLocal = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
imagemLocal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
imageViewLocal = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:imagemLocal];

[self.view addSubview: imageViewLocal];
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolver o problema relatado?

Comment: Já verificou se `imageNamed` está retornando `nil`?

Comment: Sim ja verifiquei, não está retornando nil, esta carregando a imagem normalmente. Muito estranho isso.

Comment: Atualizando pergunta!

Comment: Fiz um teste criando tudo no código, e funcionou, mas ainda prefiro usar o storyboard pois para agilizar o processo.

Comment: Faça um teste: adicione novamente a `ImageView` no Storyboard, ligue ela com a variável e troque a cor do background só pra ver se ela está visível na view atual.

Comment: Vou fazer o teste!

Comment: Sim, alterei a cor de fundo para vermelho e funcionou com a ligação da UIImageView criada pelo Storyboard

Comment: Agora funcionou!!!

 Vou postar a resposta!!! 

 muito louco o xcode hoje hein!! Minha nossa, acho que é o calor! rs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o Xcode se comportou de maneira muito estranha. Mas agora funcionou.

Eu fiz uma atribuição direta a propriedade image do Objeto. Porém já tinha tentado a mesma operação e não funcionou. Mas agora funcionou.

Obs: UIImageView adicionado a partir do Storyboard.

Código:

```
imagemLocal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
 _imageViewTesteFundo.image = imagemLocal;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta usar isso:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
    [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"image.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview: imgView];
```